# Permission denied when uploading document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

Im setting up a new server the code is running perfect on localhost put on the server it showing this.

> Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - private_data

I've tried this also`enter code here` but its not working

> chmod -R 777 private_data

In document.rb

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
 has_attached_file :document,# styles: { :original => "512x512>"},
                    :styles => {
                        :medium => "512x512>",
                        :thumb => "345x215#",
                    },
                     default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png",
                    :url=>  :set_url,
                    :path =>:set_path
  VALID_IMAGE_TYPES = ["application/pdf",'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']

  validates_attachment :document, content_type: { content_type: VALID_IMAGE_TYPES, :message=>"File can be JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF"}
  validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 8.megabytes,:message => "Your file size is larger than 7 MB, Read the instructions properly."


  private

  def set_url
    "/documents/document_viewer/:id/:style"
  end

  def set_path
    dept=Department.find(self.department_id).branch_name
    "private_data/document/#{dept}/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
  end
end
```

Comment: got it  ":rails_root/private_data/document/#{dept}/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"

Answer (score 0):

use below:

```
chmod -R 777 PATH_TO_APP/uploads 
chmod -R 777 PATH_TO_APP/tmp
```

it should help..

Comment: can you try changing the url and path as:   `has_attached_file :document,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"`

Comment: thanks but everything working perfectly on localhost it not the path and url issue , on server it showing this kind of error

Comment: @DeepakNagar dumb question but did you try to do this on the server?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes ,any solution?